# Comparing distributions of unequal sample size

Tags: distributions, t-test, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I need to test whether a series of two distributions are statistically different. The approach I have taken is to test each for normality with Shapiro Wilk before testing with a two tailed t-test if both samples are normal or testing with a Kolmogorov Smirnov test if not.

One distribution will always be an experimental sample of size 22 whilst the other distribution is from a computer model simulation and currently has a sample size of 250.

I know that P values will indicate significant differences between distributions for trivial differences between large samples but what about unequal sample sizes?

My question is: **is it good form to establish the shape of the simulation distribution as well as possible with a large sample size before comparing to the experimental distribution of smaller sample size with the t-test and KS tests?**

I could generate simulation distributions with an equal sample size to the data and I want to check there is no good reason to do this.

Comment: you should get your simulated sample size as close to $\infty$ as your resources allow!

Comment: Yes this is what I thought! This is the last thing I need to do for my biochem PhD. I don't suppose you could provide a reference to back up this approach?

Comment: I don't have a specific reference, but your approach sounds like it might be Monte Carlo type calculation. I would include a reference to this.